# Memory leak on nodejs process

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, v8, mtrace

Does anyone one have any idea what is
Module: "/lib64/libstdc++.so.6", Symbol is '_Znwm' and why it is keeping increasing memory.

I was using mtrace to see the memory usage for native modules, and I found this one use majority of the memory and does not release.

Answer (score 0):

`libstdc++` is the standard library, and `_Znmw` is `operator new`, see e.g. [What does Znwm and ZdlPv mean in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47337760/what-does-znwm-and-zdlpv-mean-in-assembly) and many other search results.

So this doesn't tell you anything in particular, only that some code creates new C++ objects. You'll have to dig deeper to identify the leaks.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are talking about garbage collection issue. This article may help you.

https://www.xarg.org/2016/06/forcing-garbage-collection-in-node-js-and-javascript/

the case is, If you have a quite complex project which allocates lots of memory, you should run gc to cleanup memory.

Comment: Triggering GC manually should never be necessary, so no, you should not do that. The whole point of automatic garbage-collection is that it's automatic ;-)