# Issue Linking C++ Library to Rust code in wasi

Tags: c++, rust, webassembly, ffi, wasi

I am trying to compile a C++ library to wasm32 wasi for use inside my rust application. However I am running into this issue.

```bash
Error: failed to run main module `target/wasm32-wasi/release/so.wasm`

Caused by:
    0: failed to instantiate "target/wasm32-wasi/release/so.wasm"
    1: unknown import: `env::_ZdlPv` has not been defined
```

This error relates to line 5 in my mylib.cpp. Which just declares a variable

```cpp
#include "OpenXLSX/OpenXLSX.hpp"

extern "C" int test() {
  std::string i = "";
  OpenXLSX::XLXmlData s;
  return 0;
}
```

my main.rs

```rust
#[link(name = "mylib")]
extern "C" {
    pub fn test() -> i32;
}

pub fn main() {
    let res = unsafe { test() };
    println!("test code: {}", res);
}
```

and my build.rs, where I assume the error is

```rust
use std::env;

fn main() {
    cc::Build::new()
        .cpp_link_stdlib(None)
        .cpp(true)
        .flag("-std=c++17")
        .archiver("llvm-ar")
        .include("OpenXLSX/external/pugixml")
        .include("OpenXLSX/external/nowide")
        .include("OpenXLSX/external/zippy")
        .include("OpenXLSX/headers")
        .include("OpenXLSX")
        .flag("--sysroot=/opt/wasi-sysroot")
        .flag("-fvisibility=default")
        .file("OpenXLSX/sources/XLCell.cpp")
        .file("OpenXLSX/sources/XLCellIterator.cpp")
        .file("OpenXLSX/sources/XLCellRange.cpp")
        .file("OpenXLSX/sources/XLCellReference.cpp")
        .file("OpenXLSX/sources/XLCellValue.cpp")
        .file("OpenXLSX/sources/XLColor.cpp")
        .file("OpenXLSX/sources/XLColumn.cpp")
        .file("OpenXLSX/sources/XLContentTypes.cpp")
        .file("OpenXLSX/sources/XLDateTime.cpp")
        .file("OpenXLSX/sources/XLDocument.cpp")
        .file("OpenXLSX/sources/XLFormula.cpp")
        .file("OpenXLSX/sources/XLProperties.cpp")
        .file("OpenXLSX/sources/XLRelationships.cpp")
        .file("OpenXLSX/sources/XLRow.cpp")
        .file("OpenXLSX/sources/XLRowData.cpp")
        .file("OpenXLSX/sources/XLSharedStrings.cpp")
        .file("OpenXLSX/sources/XLSheet.cpp")
        .file("OpenXLSX/sources/XLWorkbook.cpp")
        .file("OpenXLSX/sources/XLXmlData.cpp")
        .file("OpenXLSX/sources/XLXmlFile.cpp")
        .file("OpenXLSX/sources/XLZipArchive.cpp")
        .file("OpenXLSX/external/pugixml/pugixml.cpp")
        .compile("OpenXLSX");

    cc::Build::new()
        .archiver("llvm-ar")
        .cpp_link_stdlib(None)
        .cpp(true)
        .flag("-fvisibility=default")
        .flag("-std=c++17")
        .include("OpenXLSX/external/pugixml")
        .include("OpenXLSX/headers")
        .include("OpenXLSX")
        .flag("--sysroot=/opt/wasi-sysroot")
        .file("mylib.cpp")
        .compile("libmylib.a");
}
```

In a separate attempt, Instead of step 1 in my build.rs where I try to link the OpenXLSX files, I have also used cmake to generate a single.a file compiled for wasm32-wasi with wasi sysroot, that I tried loading.

```rust
 let src_dir = env::var("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR").unwrap();
 println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=OpenXLSX");
 println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}/wasm-libs", src_dir);
```

And I tried to generate the bindings with Bindgen, it gave me duplicate definition errors. Which is the main reason I am writing my code in a c++ function and trying to call that from rust. I assume there would still be a linking issue,even if I get bindgen to work.

Answer (score 1):

In short, your c++ code is using `operator delete(void*)` but you are **not** linking the c++ standard library that usually provides the implementation for it.

In a bit more detail:

- `_ZdlPv` is the mangled name of `operator delete(void*)`. That's the standard C++ `delete` operator that's used to free objects allocated on the heap with `new`. Check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47337760/what-does-znwm-and-zdlpv-mean-in-assembly). You can also check the name on [Demangler.com](http://demangler.com/).
- On line 5 `OpenXLSX::XLXmlData s;` you are creating an XLXmlData instance. XLXmlData has a [std::unique_ptr](https://github.com/troldal/OpenXLSX/blob/b80da42d1454f361c29117095ebe1989437db390/OpenXLSX/headers/XLXmlData.hpp#L197) as a member. So, when a `XLXmlData` object goes out of scope (at the end of `test()`) its destructor `~XLXmlData()` is called and in it, the compiler generates code to clean-up all members, including the unique_ptr. This code, contains a call to the `delete` operator.
  Check this (abridged) [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/48W4x9vPo) version of `XLXmlData` to see what code gets generated. The call to `delete` is on line 38.
- Even though `delete` is a C++ keyword, under the hood, the compiler emits just a regular function call (under the mangled `_ZdlPv` name, as we already saw), so something needs to provide the implementation for that symbol. This "something" typically is the C++ standard library.
- However, your `build.rs` passes `None` to `.cpp_link_stdlib()`. [According to the docs](https://docs.rs/cc/latest/cc/struct.Build.html#method.cpp_link_stdlib) this disables automatic linking, so the linker will not look for the implementation of `delete` in the standard library. As nothing else implements `delete`, this ultimately leads to the `unknown import` error you are seeing.

To recap, you should link with the standard library. A lot of C++ stuff simply will not work without it.

Comment: That does make a lot of sense. Removing that particular line in build.rs adds this to the wasm-ld params `-l stdc++` which seems to be what I would want here. Though wasm-ld complains that -lstdc++ cannot be found. Any idea how I would get around that?

Initially, I believed that the wasi-sysroot I provided would cover the things in the stdlib but maybe I was mistaken.